# Spring - Execute custom checks on every controller call

Tags: spring, controller

I'm working on a javax-servlet-based application and we are gradually migrating to Spring controllers.
There is an abstract Servlet all other Servlets extends that perform some checks for each call. This abstract class also contains some common methods used by all the existing Servlets.

I'm trying to replicate the same for the Spring version, but I am struggling to create a method that gets executed for every controller.

The existing abstract BaseServlet has something like:

```
protected abstract process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response);

protected final doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
  // check for specific items in session
  process(request, response)
}
```

Is there any annotation in Spring to execute something before invoking the controller's methods? Something on the line of:

```
public abstract class BaseController {

  @DoBefore
  public void check(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // look for objects in session otherwise throw exception
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you tried to move code to Spring controller?

Comment: I don't want to repeat the logic in all the controllers

Comment: In spring you would use filter for such pre handling

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is a [`HandlerInterceptor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html). There you can implement common pre-processing for all controllers / handlers.

See also https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor

Comment: Wouldn't that apply to ALL controllers, regardless of them extending my BaseController?

Comment: Yes, it would. It really depends on what you want to achieve.